# Java: Reorder elements of a multi-dimentional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I search for a memory efficient and fast way to permute the dimensions of a multi-dimensional array in Java .

By that I mean to transform the array `double[rows][cols][slices]` to the array `double[slices][rows][cols]`.(comparable to [this Matlab function](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html?refresh=true)) I know that all row elements have the same number of cols and all the cols have the same number of slices.

I always work on individual slices which makes the `double[rows][cols][slices]` arrays very unhandy. I considered to create a `getSlice(double[][][] array, int slice)` function, but my array has a size of several GB and I access the slices quite frequently. So this seems to be too much redundant work.

To precise my question:
In terms of speed and memory usage, is there any better way to permute the array dimensions than creating a new Array and copy the old one element by element? Or is there even a totally different and more elegant way to approach this which I have missed so far?

**ANSWER**
I now encapsulated the Data as suggested. For that I also used the ImagePlus, ImageStack and ImageProcessor classes from  [ImageJ](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/) as they already provided most of the functionality i need. From the memory efficiency point of view they seem to be OK.

Comment: Memory efficient *and* fast? Which would you prefer if you could only have one?

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but why do you actually need the individual slices as `double[][]` instances? Do these slices get passed as a parameter to a method accepting a `double[][]`?

Comment: Years ago I used the [cern.colt.matrix](https://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/index.html) library that has a number of useful matrix operations like this (not sure about efficiency, but probably better than building something from scratch).

Comment: "Is there any better way to permute the array dimensions than creating a new Array and copy the old one element by element?"  No, not in Java.  In other languages, you can assume array elements are contiguous and can grab a dimension with one memory process, although memory moves are still done one address at a time.

Comment: @AndyTurner: as I only have to do it once, I would pick memory efficient

Comment: @pmorken: In fact I already had a look at the cern.colt.matrix libary but could not identify a function which can do this. Which function do you had in mind?  - Thanks all for your help!

Comment: @Paul Boddington: you are correct, I have to pass them to a function I have no acces to.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't given any information about how the data is used, this may not be relevant, but I'd suggest encapsulating the data in a class, so that the data is never accessed directly.

You can make it specific to your case, or more generic. I'll show generic.

```
public interface Array3D {
    public double get(int x, int y, int z);
    /**
      * Returns a 2D view of the 3D plane for the given X, mapping (y,z) to (x,y).
      */
    public Array2D forX(int x);
    /**
      * Returns a 2D view of the 3D plane for the given Y, mapping (x,z) to (x,y).
      */
    public Array2D forY(int y);
    /**
      * Returns a 2D view of the 3D plane for the given Z.
      */
    public Array2D forZ(int z);
}
public interface Array2D {
    public double get(int x, int y);
    /**
      * Returns a 1D Y-axis view of the 2D plane for the given X.
      */
    public Array1D forX(int x);
    /**
      * Returns a 1D X-axis view of the 2D plane for the given Y.
      */
    public Array1D forY(int y);
    /**
      * Copies the data. Use sparingly.
      */
    public double[][] toArray();
}
public interface Array1D {
    public double get(int index);
    /**
      * Copies the data. Use sparingly.
      */
    public double[] toArray();
}
```

The implementation class for `Array3D` will carry the actual data. The implementation classes for `Array2D` and `Array1D` will not carry any data, as they are "views" onto the 3D data.

Comment: Encapsulating the data into a class is probably always the better way to do  it in Java. In this context however I am worried that the multiple calls of this interface functions will be too much overhead,